# Runas context menu shortcut 

Tags: windows-7, runas

In Windows 7 there is an option to enable a run as context menu by holding down the shift key when opening the start menu.  When I select the run as option a credentials dialog is shown, but it doesn't allow me to specify a domain like I can when I am using runas from the command prompt.  The domain defaults to the domain that I am logged into.

Does anyone know how I can launch an application where I can enter the credentials from another domain?  I tried domain\username but it doesn't work.

Comment: "doesn't allow me to speficy a domain", is it greyed out?

Comment: there is not domain textbox just a domain label.  I tried putting it\username and I see the domain label change to "it" but the login fails.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it should be a backslash:

```
DOMAIN\username.
```

I know the original poster said he already tried it but, actually, when I use this syntax in the credentials dialog I see the name of the domain (just under the password box) **change** according to what I type before the backslash (Windows 7 x64).

Comment: +1 I can confirm this. Start typing DOMAIN then \, as soon as you hit \ the domain will change to the new domain you specify.

Comment: I just don't get.  I just tried again and when I type domain\username I see the domain label to change to what I specify but the credentials fail.  One thing I did not mention was that this does work fine from the command prompt using this syntax:  runas /user:it\kblakeley /netonly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microso
ft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm totally off here but something in the back of my head tells me that username@domain should work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply prefix the domain name followed by a / then your username in user box. Example:

```
DOMAIN/username
```

I think this trick works for all MS Windows credential authorization boxes.